# How can I find the supported browser version for Next.js 12.3?

Tags: next.js, browser, browser-support

I want to build a Next.js 12.3 project supported by the browser versions in the image below. I have checked https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/supported-browsers, but I think it is for Next.js 13.

This is the requirement for supported browser versions when building the project:
[image]

How can I find the supported browser versions for Next.js 12.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Next.js 12 supports IE11 and all modern browsers (Chrome 61, Edge 16, Firefox 60, Opera 48, Safari 11). You can see where the code change was made for Next.js 13 [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/41529/files#diff-983ae93b98327d5c5efa5ebcf188b1c06e703492e511796b04e761971c731c9bL51-L55).